# Odoo 14 periodic actions are failing with stack trace

Tags: python, odoo-14

Odoo 14's scheduled actions are failing after upgrade from 13th version.
Can somebody suggest a way to debug it deeper or even fix?

Just one example of the error:

```
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: File: "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890, in _bootstrap
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]:   self._bootstrap_inner()
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: File: "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]:   self.run()
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: File: "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]:   self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: File: "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/server.py", line 432, in target
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]:   self.cron_thread(i)
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: File: "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/server.py", line 413, in cron_thread
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]:   ir_cron._acquire_job(db_name)
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: File: "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_cron.py", line 274, in _acquire_job
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]:   cls._process_jobs(db_name)
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: File: "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_cron.py", line 238, in _process_jobs
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]:   registry[cls._name]._process_job(job_cr, job, lock_cr)
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: File: "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_cron.py", line 148, in _process_job
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]:   cron._callback(job['cron_name'], job['ir_actions_server_id'], job['id'])
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: File: "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_cron.py", line 110, in _callback
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]:   self.env['ir.actions.server'].browse(server_action_id).run()
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: File: "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions.py", line 632, in run
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]:   res = runner(run_self, eval_context=eval_context)
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: File: "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions.py", line 501, in _run_action_code_multi
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]:   safe_eval(self.code.strip(), eval_context, mode="exec", nocopy=True)  # nocopy allows to return 'action'
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: File: "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/safe_eval.py", line 331, in safe_eval
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]:   return unsafe_eval(c, globals_dict, locals_dict)
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: File: "", line 1, in <module>
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: File: "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/stock/models/stock_rule.py", line 555, in run_scheduler
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]:   self._run_scheduler_tasks(use_new_cursor=use_new_cursor, company_id=company_id)
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: File: "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/point_of_sale/models/pos_session.py", line 1184, in _run_scheduler_tasks
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]:   super(ProcurementGroup, self)._run_scheduler_tasks(use_new_cursor=use_new_cursor, company_id=company_id)
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: File: "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/product_expiry/models/production_lot.py", line 129, in _run_scheduler_tasks
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]:   super(ProcurementGroup, self)._run_scheduler_tasks(use_new_cursor=use_new_cursor, company_id=company_id)
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: File: "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/stock/models/stock_rule.py", line 526, in _run_scheduler_tasks
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]:   orderpoints.sudo()._procure_orderpoint_confirm(use_new_cursor=use_new_cursor, company_id=company_id, raise_user_error=False)
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: File: "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/stock/models/stock_orderpoint.py", line 500, in _procure_orderpoint_confirm
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]:   self.env['procurement.group'].with_context(from_orderpoint=True).run(procurements, raise_user_error=raise_user_error)
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: File: "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/stock/models/stock_rule.py", line 426, in run
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]:   rule = self._get_rule(procurement.product_id, procurement.location_id, procurement.values)
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: File: "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/stock/models/stock_rule.py", line 482, in _get_rule
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]:   result = self._search_rule(values.get('route_ids', False), product_id, values.get('warehouse_id', False), domain)
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: File: "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/stock/models/stock_rule.py", line 470, in _search_rule
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]:   res = Rule.search(expression.AND([[('route_id', 'in', warehouse_routes.ids)], domain]), order='route_sequence, sequence', limit=1)
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: File: "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 1709, in search
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]:   return res if count else self.browse(res)
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: File: "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 4990, in browse
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]:   if not ids:
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: File: "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/osv/query.py", line 172, in __bool__
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]:   return bool(self._result)
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: File: "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/func.py", line 26, in __get__
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]:   value = self.fget(obj)
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: File: "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/osv/query.py", line 165, in _result
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]:   self._cr.execute(query_str, params)
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: File: "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in execute
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: File: "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 101, in check
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]:   return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: File: "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 301, in execute
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]:   res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: 2023-07-21 21:58:19,127 112133 INFO ? odoo.service.server: Initiating server reload
Jul 21 21:58:19 ip-172-31-33-59 odoo[112133]: 2023-07-21 21:58:19,299 112133 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: ConnectionPool(used=0/count=0/max=80): Closed 6 connections
```

But it is failing constantly and reloads every minute, which makes server close to impossible to use.

Comment: Tuning of the odoo configuration file solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuning Odoo server parameters, especially:

```
limit_memory_soft
limit_memory_hard
limit_time_real
workers
max_cron_threads
```

As suggested in:
https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/odoo14-service-keep-crash-dumping-stacktrace-of-limit-exceeding-threads-before-reloading-204504

Helped me to solve the crashes.

Answer (score 1):

In order to let you start working and slowly identify the issue that it's causing those errors a solution could be to go to the Menu `Settings/Automation/Scheduled Actions` and disable the one with the name `Procurement: run scheduler`
Then you could manually execute it in order to identify the issue when it's not affecting your working hours

Comment: Where is scheduled action located? It is in DB or somewhere in the code? I need to understand how can I run it and what to do when I found a solution.

Comment: You could run it again in the same menu, just activate it again or there is a button to execute it manually named `Run Manually`

Comment: From your posted log I cannot see the error, but seems to be an sql query error

Comment: Thanks for the hint, looks like I have faced the same issues as this one: https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/odoo14-service-keep-crash-dumping-stacktrace-of-limit-exceeding-threads-before-reloading-204504